# What do I need to install to make Data Connections in Server Explorer work?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, server-explorer, data-connections

I must have uninstalled something recently because the Data Connections no longer work.  When I try to expand the Tables node, I get this:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

### OK

What do I need to install to make it work?

Using Windows XP, VS2008 SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is a file that gets installed with [SQL Server/Express 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/).  It's part of SQL Management Objects (SMO).

Comment: This is an odd error - I was connecting to my SQL Server 2005 just fine until today when a co-worker who uses 2008 touched a database file I was using.  now VS2008 can't connect anymore.

Grrr.

Answer (score 1):

I would backup any local Databases you want to keep and then uninstall and reinstall SQL Server (and reapply the latest service pack).